# removing duplicates in ms access

Tags: sql, ms-access

please tell me how to write this query

i have an access table

```
number
2
2
1
2
2
1
1
3
2
```

i want a query that gives

```
number     count
2            5
1            3
3            1
```

any help appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

something like...

```
SELECT number, count(number) AS count
FROM table
GROUP BY number
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a bad idea to have a column named number since it is a reserved keyword.

You probably want something like

```
select number_, count(*) as count from ... group by number_
```